# C/C++ mangling?

Tags: support, tags

Observed with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470530/does-c-c-have-a-delay-function): the tag text

```
c c++
```

is displayed as **one** tag:

```
cc++
```

Is this intentional?

**Update**: 5 minutes later it is displayed as expected. What is going on?

---

[alt text http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/SO/cAndcppMangling4c.png](http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/SO/cAndcppMangling4c.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1470530/list), it was misspelled and corrected.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The edit must have happend in the few seconds between displaying the page and pressing the Retag button.

Answer (score 1):

There are no more questions tagged `cc++`.  No more worries!